# Probability of Hops to Nodes

Tags: statistics, graph-theory

A graph has N nodes, and each node is connected to exactly M other nodes. Which nodes are connected is randomly determined.

.04N of these nodes are red, and the remaining .96N are black, and a node's color is randomly determined. How would one determine the value of M such that, on average for any black node, the shortest distance to a red node is two edges?

---

*This is my first time posting in this StackExchange and I'm not normally a math person, so apologies if the question is phrased poorly.*

Comment: Are you able to answer the warm-up: Given $M$ and $N$, what fraction of black nodes are directly attached to a red node?  (Call that set "distance 1".  One could then ask, how many of the non-distance 1 black nodes are connected to a distance 1 black node?)

Comment: Thinking out loud. A red node has M connections, each with a 96% chance of being black. So any red node is connected to .96M black nodes. .96M*.04N would account for every red node's connection, but it would be too high because some black nodes might be connected to more than one red node. So, .0384MN-(the number of times after the first that a black node is connected to a red node)

Comment: Wait, I think I did that backwards. Any black node connection has a 4% chance of being red. This is still going to end up being .0384MN-(the number of times two red connects to one black). But that seems like it requires knowing (chance of 2 reds being connected to one black) + (chance of three reds being connected to one black) + (chance of four) + ...

Comment: Do you know anything more about the graph? The answer (to the original question) requires something more about the graph's structure. To consider an extreme case, if the graph consists of $\frac{N}{M+1}$ components, which are cliques on $M+1$ nodes, then no black node will *ever* be two steps away from a red node, because no two nodes are two steps away.

Comment: I hope I'm understanding your question right. Are you saying that for a high enough M, the average must be below 2? (For example, 100 nodes, each with 99 connections, forces every node to be connected to every other node and thus every black node is 1 step away from a red.) In that case, M is too large, and I'm trying to determine a smaller value of M.
I forgot to specify in the original question so I'll edit it in: the edges between nodes are also randomly determined.

Comment: If the edges are also chosen at random, that's enough to avoid (with high probability) the thing I was describing.